Ellipsis attributes name in Attributes Window in Android Studio
I'm building a project in android studio but suddenly the attributes name became ellipsis even though I have big screen. the attributes name before was not ellipsis
I'm expecting the full attributes nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
